# Flushing portions of a Redis cache

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I'm investigating the use of Redis in an asp.net mvc application using the [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) client and a single Redis instance running on a remote machine.

Our cache is broken up into 3 major "areas" (Asp.net output cache, NHibernate second level cache, application cache) and I would like to have the ability able to "flush" all of the keys in these areas individually.

In Couchbase (which we currently utilize) this would be accomplished by using separate [buckets](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#vbuckets) with a client instance pointing to each one. We could then flush all values in these buckets using a single call from the appropriate client instance.

Is there a way to accomplish a setup like this using Redis? If so, how do I approach this from the client/server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three approaches to achieve that.

#### Shared Databases - Worst Approach (as in highly recommended not to pursuit)

Redis supports shared databases that are basically separate keyspaces managed by the same server. After connecting to your Redis, you switch between the databases with the [SELECT](http://redis.io/commands/select) statement and you can use the [FLUSHDB](http://redis.io/commands/flushdb) command to flush each one individually.

Pro:

- This is the simplest way to get exactly what you need.

Cons:

- Shared databases share the same Redis process. Since Redis is (mostly) single-threaded, the practice of using shared databases is not recommended as operations in one database can interfere with other databases running on the same server.
- It isn't clear whether support for shared databases will be continued in future versions of Redis.

(For more information on Shared vs. Dedicated Redis databases, check out my post at http://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances)

#### One Database, Different Key Prefixes - Slightly Better but still...

You could use a single Redis database and prefix you keys according to the "area" they belong to (e.g. keys that go into the ASP.Net area will be prefixed with 'asp:' etc...). To delete an area, iterate through the keyspace with the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command using the relevant key name pattern and [DEL](http://redis.io/commands/del) the results it returns.

Pros: can't think of any
Cons:

- Same as the above + more coding to implement the SCAN/DEL routine.

#### Dedicated Databases - Recommended Approach

Use a separate Redis instance for each area, plain and simple. Set up your remote machine to run 3 Redis servers, each managing its own keyspace. To flush, connect to the relevant database and do FLUSHDB or [FLUSHALL](http://redis.io/commands/flushall).

Pros:

- Flush an area with a single command
- Leverage multiple cores on the remote machine

Con:

- Could mean a little more administrative effort to set up 3 Redis servers.

Lastly, if you're looking for a way to use Redis without the hassle, I urge you to consider [Redis Cloud](http://redislabs.com/redis-cloud) as an option for a hosted Redis service in the Cloud. We are the only service provider that lets you set up **multiple, dedicated** Redis databases in the same subscription at no extra cost.

Comment: Thank you for such a concise answer! It sounds like running multiple instances is probably the way to go for us. Regarding Redis Cloud - that *would* be an option for us if you had a POP in Canada (due to client restrictions - we can't store anything outside of the country, I'm afraid).